# There's any issue if I don't place my models into a specific folder inside the app directory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am following a tutorial where the tutor places all of his models inside the following path app>models.

I'm not willing to do that, but he is always talking about best practices like the one I'm talking about.

So, there's any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though Laravel is a MVC framework (Model-View-Controller), we don't see a folder called Model in L5 and above.

People often tend to add everything in a folder called Model just as to group all models together, but it's optional in L5 and above.

But yeah, it's always good to keep everything under a folder called Model in my opinion.

Laravel just doesn't bottleneck you or your project into using any one method. This is something for you (and your development team, if you're a part of one) to decide on. That is the convention behind Laravel - giving you the developer choice in the matter.